# how to override the placeholder icons în AEM 6?

Tags: css, aem

I would like to override the `icons of the cq component placeholders`.I have found the Icons here:
http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/ui/widgets/themes/default.css
`example:` The placeholder icon for the `Image Component` is difined here

```
.cq-image-placeholder {
    background: url("default/placeholders/img.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now I would like to override the `img.png` with `myImg.png`. I have expended my the css file content\src\main\content\jcr_root\apps\myProject\components\content\image\clientlibs\image.css of the image Component as follow:

```
.cq-image-placeholder {
    background: url("myImg.png") !important;
}
```

but nothing change.

How to override the placeholder icons in http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/ui/widgets/themes/default.css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit the css file to your project and then overwrite the changes. You should never overwrite libs folder.

You can follow the steps below to achieve custom icons.

1. Create a cq folder in apps.
2. create folder structure /apps/cq/ui/widgets/themes

Note: Check for any extra properties to folder in  /libs/cq/ui/widgets.If you find any properties here please add them to these  /apps/cq/ui/widgets folders also.

3. Copy default.css to /apps/cq/ui/widgets
4. Edit your css file here.

If you want change the icon image, you can also follow the steps from 1 to 4 for that particular image and override it.